# Qt5 QTcpSocket derived class and QTcpServer

Tags: c++, qt5, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I'm developing an application that made sense that I wrapped my classes around the implemented QTcpSocket (since it's a TCP protocol, and I need to be able to use the raw socket and the added features as seemlessly as possible).

So, for the sake of simplicity, my code is structured like this:

```
class MyTCPSocket : public QTcpSocket
{
 Q_OBJECT
 // ....
}

class MyTCPServer : public QTcpServer
{
 Q_OBJECT
 // ....
}
```

And with QTcpServer, the default nextPendingConnection() function returns an instance of QTcpSocket, which I can't cast up to MyTCPSocket (as far as I'm aware, QTcpSocket doesn't have a copy constructure).

What's my best option for handing this?  I was thinking that I could create a new MyTCPSocket and simply set the socket descriptor to the one returned by nextPendingConnection() from MyTCPServer, but I wasn't sure how that would work when the old socket gets deleted.

Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly that: override `incomingConnection` but don't call the base class, instead create an instance of your `QTcpSocket` subclass and use `setSocketDescriptor` on it. If you want to keep QTcpSocket "signal behaviour", also call `addPendingConnection` and emit `newConnection`.

Then just downcast the socket you get from `nextPendingConnection` to your QTcpSocket subclass.